# Code inside AsyncTask doesn't run smoothly when screen is off

Tags: android, android-asynctask, screen

Inside my AsyncTask I vibrate the phone in a certain pattern and repeat this until the user turns it off. This works fine as long as the screen is on. If the screen is off, the code still runs but with periodic breaks in between. It seems like Android tries to consume battery with the screen off and only runs code within threads (like my AsyncTask) only periodically. Is that true? Or is this some other behavior? Is there a way I can get my code to run smoothly even with the screen off? Turning on the screen could drain the battery. The vibration is used to notify the user even when the screen is off.

Comment: for quick solution, I think you can make your screen awake until user interface. I am also looking forward if they are any really good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). By using a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` you can ensure that even though your screen is off, cpu is running and your code will execute properly.

However, I would like to add that I've never run into such problems with `AsyncTask`, But if you are running into such problems a wake lock would probably be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is not designed to handle long running tasks. If you want your phone to vibrate in a specific pattern for a long time, I'd suggest to use set repeating alarm using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Not sure where you got your info on AsyncTask not being designed for long running tasks. On the contrary, it IS and I use it extensively throughout my app quite nicely.

Comment: Sure you can, but there are pitfalls. On http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html is says "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.". So that is just the way I interpreted it.